# ReactJS material UI form validation with formik

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, formik

I am trying to implement validate a phone number field with `reactjs` `material ui` and `formik`

I read huge article on it, yet i couldn't implement this in my way.

I am submitting Reproduce-able code of my component here:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { FormGroup } from '@material-ui/core';

import {
  Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage,
} from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';


function App(props) {

  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    phone: '',
  });


  const handleChange = name => event => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
  };


  const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    phone: Yup.string("")
      .min(11, "phone must contain atleast 11 characters")
      .required("Enter your phone"),
  });



  return (

    <React.Fragment>

      <FormGroup autoComplete="on">
        <TextField
          id=""
          label="Phone"
          value={values.phone}
          onChange={handleChange('phone')}
          type="number"
          name='phone'
        />
      </FormGroup>

    </React.Fragment>

  );
}


export default connect(null)(App);
```

Can anyone help me to achieve the validation? I am trying for last 6 days and read full documentation but i failed to do it yet.

It would be much appreciated if anyone can help me in this case?

Answer (score -1):

Please use `'material-ui-phone-number'. It will validate the input via mask. You don't have to get your hand dirty. But you might need to sanitize phone number value return from Formik.

```
import MuiPhoneNumber from 'material-ui-phone-number'

<Field
  name="phoneNumber"
  label={t('Phone Number')}
  component={MuiPhoneNumber}
  variant="outlined"
  defaultCountry="mm"
  fullWidth
  onChange={v => setFieldValue('phoneNumber', v)}
  helperText={touched.phoneNumber ? t(errors.phoneNumber) : ''}
  error={touched.phoneNumber && Boolean(errors.phoneNumber)} />
```